# User profiles and organic groups

Tags: users, organic-groups

I'm working on a site's structure and I'm not sure where to start. I could use some general advice.

My Goals:

- Personal and professional groups (organic groups)
- Two types of user accounts - personal/professional (profile2)
- Account may contain sub-users i.e. mom dad brother sister (subuser)
- Users can belong to both personal and professional groups
- Users can create both personal and professional groups
- Professional groups and personal groups require different fields

User X belongs to two or three groups using a personal profile but manages a professional group with a professional profile. Or vice versa.

I could put the fields I want in either the group or the profile but I'm not sure which is the better practice. A friend suggested to make a content type for the user profiles to prevent clutter with the user entity. Hell - I may be going about this all wrong.

I'm not looking for step-by-step instructions - just a push in the right direction.

Thanks